# msql count of items in each category into 2 columns by status with join

Tags: mysql

I’m a mysql newbie, recently installed mariadb to work on a project.
I have one table of many ITEMS, which are in various categories (catnum), and another table, STATUS, showing items (by id#) and their current status, either A or B. 
I need to write a query that lists all of the categories (by catnum) and the total of all A’s and B’s in each category, something like this:

Desired result:

```
catnum      statA    statB  
1001        22      15
1002        0       12
1003        14      8
1004        3       37
1005        24      0
1006        0       1
1007        47      5
etc
```

The ITEMS table looks like this:

```
itemid  catnum  
1       1205
2       1008
3       1010
4       1150
5       1782
6       1553
7       1004
etc
```

The STATUS table looks like this:

```
itemid  stat    
60      A
302     A
95      B
122     B
8       B
6       A
46      B
etc
```

The itemid in ITEMS is auto_increment, in case that matters.
I know (or think I know) that I need to use the following in some combination:

```
count(status.stat) or count(status.stat = A)
where items.itemid = status.itemid
where stat = A (then B)
group by catnum.
```

In some combinations I got error saying “Unknown column 'status.itemid' in 'having clause'” or other clause, despite that it exists. Why is that? 
The closest I have gotten is to show each category and both status columns properly labeled but the number of B status items was incorrect, just a repeat of number of A status items.

```
SELECT 
    items.catnum, 
    count(status.stat=1) AS statA, 
    count(status.stat=2) AS statB
FROM 
    status
INNER JOIN 
    items 
WHERE 
    items.itemid = status.itemid 
GROUP BY 
    catnum;
```

(ALSO tried with ON instead of WHERE, same result, statB totals were wrong.)

I have explored self joins, inner joins, left/right joins, unions, subquery, and other techniques but I can’t seem to get to what I want. It seems like this must be a really common general query, but I can’t seem to find the right search terms to find it online. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query as it currently stands will simply return a COUNT of all the items in `STATUS` which have a given `catnum`. This is why the values for `statA` and `statB` are the same. What you need to do is `SUM` the occurrences of each status value. I've made a small [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01167b/1) demo that shows this query in action:

```
SELECT 
    items.catnum, 
    SUM(status.stat='A') AS statA, 
    SUM(status.stat='B') AS statB
FROM items
JOIN status 
ON items.itemid = status.itemid 
GROUP BY items.catnum
```

Output (for the demo data):

```
catnum  statA   statB
1004    1       1
1008    2       1
1010    0       2
```

Note that in MySQL a boolean expression (e.g. `status.stat='A'`) evaluates to 1 if true, 0 if false, so it can be summed directly.

Comment: Wow, Nick, that was so easy and simple. And quick. Thanks much, it works like a dream. Saved me days of brain-flogging.